# Failed type migration for Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I recently migrated from Eclipse to Intellij, and while exploring Intellij I came across type Migration under refactoring. Naturally, I attempted to test type migration out using an existing repository, but when I first tried it on this line:

```
private static final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> ALL_PERSONS = new ArrayList<>();
```

I got this:

[image]

So, I wondered if the issue is because:

1. the variable is private
2. the variable is static
3. the variable is declared as `final`

To test this, I deleted parts of the signature one at a time (e.g. testing with `private final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> ALL_PERSONS` instead), but the same situation still resulted.

I tried to Google this problem as well, but there seems to be little mention of this. So while I suspect that this is a newbie mistake, I hope someone can illuminate why type migration fails in this case. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Type Migration refactoring is selectable if a type is highlighted, or the cursor is fixed at it before bringing up the refactor menu.  So, from your example, highlight/point at `ArrayList`, `HashMap`, or `String` first.

The refactoring would still apply to the class field, `ALL_PERSONS`.

I tested on IDEA 2017.2.